# How to manipulate awk output?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

If I type

```
echo '"";"";" 01.06.2011";"7";"01.06";"-21,00";"-6.097,73";' | awk -F';' '{print $3 " " $7}'
```

then I get

```
" 01.06.2011" "-6.097,73"
```

but what I would like is

```
" 01.06.2011" "-6097"
```

How should that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just manipulate `$7` to remove the characters you don't want:

```
awk -F';' '{
  gsub(/[.]/, "", $7)
  sub(/,[0-9]*/, "", $7)
  print $3, $7
}'
```

Comment: What does `[.]` mean? I can guess that it removes the `.`, but why are  the square brackets needed?

Comment: A dot in a regular expression is a wildcard that will match any single character. However a dot within a bracket expression has no special meaning: it's just a dot. Another way to write that is with an escape: `gsub(/\./, "", $7)`

Answer (score 3):

<strike>AWK supports the [printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html) function, and, from memory, parses as much of a string as an integer as it can. So, from your example:</strike>

`awk -F';' '{printf("%s %i", $3, $7*1000);}'`

would work. This will work for any size number, too…

(above doesn't work due to double quotes in the data, see below…)

**EDIT:** If you're using gawk, you can achieve this stably using a combination of [printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html) and [strtonum](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

`awk -F';' '{
  gsub(/"/, "", $7); 
  printf("%s \"%i\"\n", $3, strtonum($7)*1000);
}'`

The `gsub()` call strips off the quotes so that `strtonum` doesn't choke on them, and then the  `printf` call puts them back as part of the format string…

Comment: It outputs `" 01.06.2011" 0`.

Answer (score 2):

This will work. Uses [split()](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html).

```
echo '"";"";" 01.06.2011";"7";"01.06";"-21,00";"-6.097,73";' | awk -F';' '{ split($7, a, ",") split(a[1], b, "."); print $3 " " b[1] b[2]"\""}'
```

or a combination of `split()` and `sub()`.

```
awk -F';' '{ split($7, a, ",");b = a[1]; sub(/\./, "",a[1]);  print $3 " " a[1] "\""}'
```

or just using `sub()`

```
awk -F';' '{ sub(/,.*/, "", $7); sub(/\./, "", $7) ;print $3 " " $7 "\""}'
```

Relevant Doc:

> **split(string, array, fieldsep)**
>
> This divides string into pieces
>   separated by fieldsep, and stores the pieces in array. The first piece
>   is stored in array[1], the second piece in array[2], and so forth. The
>   string value of the third argument, fieldsep, is a regexp describing
>   where to split string (much as FS can be a regexp describing where to
>   split input records). If the fieldsep is omitted, the value of FS is
>   used. split returns the number of elements created. The split
>   function, then, splits strings into pieces in a manner similar to the
>   way input lines are split into fields. For example:
>
> split("auto-da-fe", a, "-") splits the string `auto-da-fe' into three
>   fields using`-' as the separator.
>
> It sets the contents of the array a
>   as follows: a[1] = "auto" a[2] = "da" a[3] = "fe"

Comment: It is very close. I gives `" 01.06.2011" "-6.097"`. The `.` should also be removed.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting Corrected. May be there is a better way, but this works.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the gsub function:

```
echo '"";"";" 01.06.2011";"7";"01.06";"-21,00";"-6.097,73";' | awk -F';' '{gsub(/(,.*|\.)/,"",$7);print $3" "$7"\"";}'
```

It can match more than one criteria. That's maybe shortest solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the comma and double-quote as a field separators and accommodate accordingly

```
awk -F'[";,]' '{print "\""$8 " \""$21*1000"\""}'
```

#### Output

```
$ awk -F'[";,]' '{print "\""$8 " \""$21*1000"\""}' <<<'"";"";" 01.06.2011";"7";"01.06";"-21,00";"-6.097>
" 01.06.2011 "-6097"
```